# SmackException NoResponseException on sending Xmpp message back to sender

Tags: tomcat, xmpp, openfire, smack

Pre-note:   I've checked other threads on stackoverflow and didn't find similar case.
We are facing strange problem regarding xmpp on our production server. Environment is like this:
2 tomcats (v7), 1 openfire (3.10), ngnix

We have mobile apps (android, ios) as client and they are talking to our server via xmpp. Our server is also another user for openfire (but has admin role) that is connecting to openfire via SASL and self signed certificate. It is using smack 4.1.0.

So we have this problem. Everything goes well on running environment. Clients-Server are communicating. But when we need to make new deployment, we stop tomcat-deploy war-start tomcat (for each tomcat so that we wouldn't have downtime). Server initializes without problem. Smack logs show me that connection is established with openfire and also authenticated. Also i can see that chat messages coming from clients. But somehow, server cannot send message back to clients.
While sending chat messages, there is no exception thrown like it is successful. But while publishing something on node on openfire (as admin role), there is this:

```
*Unable to publish notification to node [NODENAME] , ex [org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 30000ms (~30s). Used filter: IQReplyFilter: iqAndIdFilter (AndFilter: (OrFilter: (IQTypeFilter: type=error, IQTypeFilter: type=result), StanzaIdFilter: id=H0ttG-44)), : fromFilter (OrFilter: (FromMatchesFilter (full): pubsub.SERVERNAME.com)).], cause [null], class [org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException]*
```

This problem lasts about 20-25 mins. And later somehow everything becomes normal and clients-server can communicate in both ways.

There is no 'connection lost' or 'reconnecting' logs on the connection listener. We found nothing useful that will help us what is going on there for 20 mins that communication is one way and then it becomes ok after 20-25 mins

Here is our configuration for xmpp connection:

```
    // We are using two-way authentication with certificates
SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism(new SASLExternalMechanism());
XmppTrustManager xmppTrustManager = null;
try {
    xmppTrustManager = new XmppTrustManager($truststore.path, $truststore.password);
} catch (final XMPPException e) {
    log.error("Unable to create trust manager", e);
    throw new...
}

final TrustManager[] trustManagers = new TrustManager[] { xmppTrustManager };
XmppKeyManager xmppKeyManager = null;
try {
    xmppKeyManager = new XmppKeyManager($keystore.path, $keystore.password);

} catch (final XMPPException e) {
    log.error("Unable to create key manager", e);
    throw new ...
}
final KeyManager[] keyManagers = new KeyManager[] { xmppKeyManager };

SSLContext sslContext = null;
try {
    sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);
} catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    log.error("Cannot create SSLContext instance", e);
} catch (final KeyManagementException e) {
    log.error("Cannot initialize SSLContext instance", e);
}

final XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
        .setHost($host)
        .setPort($port)
        .setServiceName($domain).setCustomSSLContext(sslContext)
        .setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(final String hostname, final SSLSession session) {
                return $domain.equals(hostname);
            }
        }).setDebuggerEnabled(false).allowEmptyOrNullUsernames().build();

final XMPPTCPConnection xmppConnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
xmppConnection.setPacketReplyTimeout(30 * 1000);
// xmppConnection.addConnectionListener(connectionListener());
ReconnectionManager.getInstanceFor(xmppConnection).enableAutomaticReconnection();
xmppConnection.setUseStreamManagement(true);

xmppConnection.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener() {

    @Override
    public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
        log.info("Successfully reconnected to the XMPP server.");
    }

    @Override
    public void reconnectionFailed(final Exception e) {
        log.info("Failed to reconnect to the XMPP server ", e.toString());

    }

    @Override
    public void reconnectingIn(final int seconds) {
        log.debug("Reconnecting in " + seconds + " seconds.");
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionClosedOnError(final Exception e) {
        log.info("Connection to XMPP server was lost ", e.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionClosed() {
        log.info("Connection to XMPP server was closed");
    }

    @Override
    public void connected(final XMPPConnection connection) {
        log.info("connected to XMPP server");
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticated(final XMPPConnection connection, final boolean resumed) {
        log.info("Xmpp connected authenticated. is resumed: " + resumed);

    }
});

log.debug("xmppConnection bean is initialized");
return xmppConnection;
```

And connection code is on onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event):

```
    if (connecting) {
    return;
}
connecting = true;

try {
    xmppConnection.connect();
    xmppConnection.login("", "", "");
    log.debug("no exception occured during connection");
} catch (XMPPException | SmackException | IOException e) {
    // start a new thread that will try connecting every pingInterval seconds
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!xmppConnection.isConnected()) {
                log.debug("waiting for a while to attempt login again");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
                    xmppConnection.connect();
                    xmppConnection.login("", "", "");                   
                } catch (XMPPException | SmackException | IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!